# All Pages visible on the Frontpage

Tags: pages, frontpage

I use the Theme Twenty Seventeen in WordPress to create my website. Here all pages are one below the other seen on the frontpage. Now I added a new page, but this is not listed on the frontpage. I can only reach it by clicking on it on the menu.

How can I also list that page on the frontpage?
Please explain step by step cause I'm not experienced in creating websites.

Answer (score 2):

In Twenty Seventeen you can only add 4 page in front-page section. see image below

[image]

See `Appearance`=> `Customize` => `Theme Options`

**Update**

You can add extra section with filter `twentyseventeen_front_page_sections` add this code in `functions.php`

```
function tws_custom_front_sections( $num_sections )
    {
        return 5; //Change this number to change the number of the sections.
    }
add_filter( 'twentyseventeen_front_page_sections', 'tws_custom_front_sections' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Could you explain it to me step by step as I'm not experienced in programming. Where do I find functions.php on the dashboard?

Comment: On the admin dashboard go-to `Appearance` -> `Editor` -> on the right bar you can find theme files `Theme Functions` add your code there and update file.

Answer (score 0):

On the frontpage (and on other archives) only posts are listed by default. If you want to add new article and make it visible on that list, you should publish it as a post.

On the other hand, the pages are more static articles that are not listed on archive pages - it makes no sense to put "Contact" page on such list. So you can access them from navigation menus and so on.

PS. You can modify this behavior and make pages to show on archive pages, but it will involve some coding - and I don't think there is a need for such steps in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are you sure only Posts are listed? Look at my website www.drum-on-air.de Here you see that pages like "Videos", "Info" or "Blog" are listed on the frontpage. Likewise I would also like the other Pages like "Audio" and "machs selbst" to be listed there. Wouldnt that be possible?